# How to resolve with a default class if a matching register is not found in Autofac

Tags: autofac

I am using the following code for register:

```
builder.RegisterType<QCatVCardParser>().Named<IQCatParser>(".VCF");              
builder.RegisterType<QCatVCardParser>().Named<IQCatParser>(".VCARD");            
builder.RegisterType<QCatOutlookMessageParser>().Named<IQCatParser>(".MSG");
builder.RegisterType<QCatMimeMessageParser>().Named<IQCatParser>(".EML");
builder.RegisterType<QCatCalendarParser>().Named<IQCatParser>(".ICS");
container = builder.Build();
```

To retrieve a class reference I am using the below code:

```
var r = container
    .ResolveNamed<IQCatParser>(Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToUpperInvariant());
```

Now my question is if a unsuppoted file extension comes let's say .DOC I want to resolve it with a component among one of the registered classes or else with the first registered class.

Is it possible to do this with AutoFac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Autofac. You need to create an `IRegistrationSource` that can provide the default registration if needed. For example, here is the `RegistrationsFor` code of a source that provides settings classes:

```
var typedService = service as IServiceWithType;
if (typedService != null && typedService.ServiceType.IsClass && typeof(ISettings).IsAssignableFrom(typedService.ServiceType))
{
    yield return RegistrationBuilder.ForDelegate((c, p) => c.Resolve<ISettingsReader>().Load(typedService.ServiceType))
                .As(typedService.ServiceType)
                .CreateRegistration();
}
```

Then, inside of a module or directly using your Autofac builder, call `RegisterSource` to hook up the new registration source.

Comment: I want to resolve it based on name not by service type so can you please explain the code with respect to that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to write the code for you. This is a great start though that with some tweaking will let you write a registration source based on names.